# How do I update a listbox when a radio button is changed?

Tags: c#

I have a form that is like a registration for school, and there is two radio buttons. I am supposed to have a listbox that has roles for each of the two radio buttons, but I can not figure out how to update the list box to the different roles when the radio button is changed. Here is my code

```
private void PopulateBoxes()
        {
            try // Assure that input file specified is readable
            {
                if (liveActionRadioButton.Checked == true)
                {
                    StreamReader inputFile; // Declare StreamReader object for use in reading files
                    inputFile = File.OpenText("LiveActionClasses.txt"); // Open file with flavors information
                    while (!inputFile.EndOfStream) // Verify that more data exists to be read
                    {
                        // Read a line from input file and add it to combo box
                        availableClassesListBox.Items.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
                    }
                    inputFile.Close(); // Close input file after reading data
                }
                else if (animationRadioButton.Checked == true)
                {
                    inputFile = File.OpenText("AnimationClasses.txt"); // Open file with toppings information
                    while (!inputFile.EndOfStream) // Verify that more data exists to be read
                    {
                        // Read a line from input file and add it to list box
                        availableClassesListBox.Items.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
                    }
                    inputFile.Close(); // Close input file after reading data
                }
            }



            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

The files read in from the bin/debug folder. It loads the first set of roles I need, but will not change and I'm not sure what to do

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0